# Private members visible outside the class

Tags: class, c++-cli, class-members

Why is it that I can see private members of my class in a Quick Watch window when the breakpoint is outside that class?

My breakpoint is in ConsoleApplication.cpp
My class is defined in XmlSignature.h

I can see these private members: **Transforms_Root_element**, **xmlDocument**

Here's my class:

```
ref class XmlReference
{
public:
    XmlReference(String^ URI);
    virtual ~XmlReference();

    String^ URI;
    XmlElement^ Reference_element;

    String^ ns_ds = "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#";

    XmlNode^ AddTransform(String^ strAlgorithm);
    XmlNode^ AddTransform(String^ strAlgorithm, String^ strParameterName, String^ strParameter);

    List<XmlNode^>^ Transforms = gcnew List<XmlNode^>;
private:

    XmlNode^ Transforms_Root_element = nullptr;
    XmlDocument^ xmlDocument;

    //Called by AddTransform
    XmlNode^ CreateTransformElement(String^ strAlgorithm);
};
```

This is what I can see:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a feature and helps when debugging :-).
Class member visibility is ensured by the compiler to enforce object orientated programming. As @Medinoc observed, .net runtime also protects private and protected memory of a class from being accessed from other contexts.

In any case, the debugger has full access to the memory and can show all member content.

Comment: Note that it *is* secured at runtime in that private members cannot be accessed through reflection without the `MemberAccess` `ReflectionPermission` flag. On the other hand, everything in your program has full trust until you start explicitly executing plug-ins in separate AppDomains;

Comment: It is: Reflection, Code Access Security etc., it all ties with the .Net security model. Of course, the debugger doesn't have to care about this: The debugger has direct access on the memory of the debugged program regardless of other security considerations, so it just looks where the PDB says the data is and displays it as it pleases.

Comment: Thanks, I tried to clarify this in the answer. Did not see c++-cli label before.